# What happens if an <iostream> function fails?

Tags: c++, iostream

Transforming an old C function of mine to C++. I stumbled on the problem that i do not find the documentation for `<iostream>` behavior in case of an error.

Just as one example - this old C function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int OldFixedInterfaceWithErrorReturn(void)
{
    int e = 0;
    int ret = printf("This prototype is fixed - never change the function type.\n");
    e |= (ret == -1);
    return e;
}
```

Can not be transformed to this new C++ function because of missing error handling.

```
#include <iostream>
int OldFixedInterfaceWithErrorReturn()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    int e = 0;
    //int ret = 
    cout << "This prototype is fixed - never change the function type." << endl;
    //e |= (ret == -1);
    return e;
}
```

I was unable to find the documentation on this. Where can i find documentation for `<iostream>` function errors?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream

Comment: Check the streamstate. That said, check out booleans and exceptions, too.

Comment: It is a valid function definition in C++ though, the explicit void parameterlist is not necessary and typically frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iostreams can fail for two different reasons, with either [`failbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) or [`badbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). The `failbit` failure is common on input streams and happens when your input is different than your expectation, e.g., user inputs `hello` instead of `123`. The `badbit` is set when something bad happens with the stream itself. It usually means that file cannot be read or written; basically OS level failure. There is also [`eofbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) but I do not consider it a failure flag.

If you are only concerned about `cout` output failure, I suggest setting up exception to be thrown on `failbit` and/or `badbit`: [`stream.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit | std::ios_base::failbit);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

Replace `e |= (ret == -1);` with `e |= !cout;`

Iostreams have implicit conversion to `bool` which will be `false` if one of the error flags is set, and `true` otherwise.  The error flags are set when an error occurs during an operation (and remain set until you clear them).